# FB share plain text without URL link

Tags: facebook, share

I want to share plain text from my web to Facebook without a URL link, I have read the Facebook API, and I found that if I want to share the plain text I must input them to the share page, and Facebook cannot get the text automatically.

Is my conclusion correct?If I am wrong, what should I do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Without a link, you have nothing _to_ share. This would just be a normal status update post then - but for those you are not allowed to specify the message for the user, they have to type that in themselves. (And you would have to make it via API, there is no dialog for that - so that means user has to login to your app and grant it permission first.)

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script>
function fbs_click() { 
u = location.href;
t = document.title;
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(u) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(t), 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
return false; }
</script>
```

```html
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

see : https://spigotdesign.com/text-only-facebook-share-link/